# Using EF Power Tools - Retrieving Decimal Precision and Scale

Tags: entity-framework, t4

I need to set the Precision and Scale values for decimal fields.

Using the EF Powertools templates, I would like to customize this section within Mapping.tt:

```
foreach (var prop in efHost.EntityType.Properties)
{
    var type = (PrimitiveType)prop.TypeUsage.EdmType;
    var isKey = efHost.EntityType.KeyMembers.Contains(prop);
    var storeProp = efHost.PropertyToColumnMappings[prop];
    var sgpFacet = storeProp.TypeUsage.Facets.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "StoreGeneratedPattern");
    var storeGeneratedPattern = sgpFacet == null
        ? StoreGeneratedPattern.None
        : (StoreGeneratedPattern)sgpFacet.Value;

    // Other code from Mapping.tt

    if (type.ClrEquivalentType == typeof(decimal))
    {
        int precision = **[Retrieve Precision Value]**;
        int scale =  **[Retrieve Scale Value]**;

        configLines.Add(String.Format(".HasPrecision({0}, {1})", precision, scale));
     }
}
```

How do I retrieve the **precision** and **scale** values for each?

Thanks.

Steve

Answer (score 1):

you can do it as following.

```
    if (edmType.ClrEquivalentType == typeof(decimal))
    {            
        Facet precisionFacet=  property.TypeUsage.Facets.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Precision");    
        Facet scaleFacet =  property.TypeUsage.Facets.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Scale");                

        hasPrecision=String.Format(".HasPrecision({0}, {1})", precisionFacet.Value, scaleFacet.Value);

     }
    if(!entityPropertyToColumnMapping.Item2.Keys.Contains(property)) continue;
    string hasColumnName = string.Format(".HasColumnName(\"{0}\")", entityPropertyToColumnMapping.Item2[property].Name);
    if(property.Name=="AccountID"){blnHasAccountId=true;}
```

## >

```
      this.Property(t => t.<#= property.Name#>)<#=hasColumnName+ hasPrecision + generateOption + required + unicCode + fixedLength + maxLength #>;
```

<#

Comment: Can you edit your answer as there are obvious typo in the formating.